# How to modify UL tag's default attributes in widget::Nav items YII2

Tags: html, css, yii2, frontend, nav

I'm new to yii2,
I've tried to make a dropdown list which contains sub-dropdowns but the UL tag of sub-dropdown (And dropdown) should contain my personal class, However, I don't know how to modify UL tag's attributes as array ($options) changes LI tag attributes

This is the form of LI AND UL tag after rendering to HTML:

```
<li>

  <ul> //How to customize UL



    <li></li>

      <ul> //How to customize UL

        <li></li>

        <li></li>

      </ul>

  </ul>

</li>
```

And this is my Code:

```
 $menuItems = [

    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
    ['label' => 'Pages', 'items' => [


        ['label' => '1', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ['label' => '2', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ['label' => '3', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ['label' => '4', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
        ['label' => '5', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
            ['label' => 'Dropdown', 'items' => [

                ['label' => '6', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                ['label' => '7', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                ['label' => '8', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                ['label' => '9', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
                ['label' => '10', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],


            ],

                'options' => ['class'=>['widget' => 'dropdown']]
            ],



    ],

        'options' => ['class'=>'cn-dropdown-item'],

    ],


];
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are talking about `Nav` widget from `yii2-bootstrap` package. If so - it's true that `options` is to add HTML attributes for `li` element but only when you use it inside `item` element, otherwise it adds HTML attributes for `ul`. To make it clearer:

```
echo \yii\bootstrap\Nav::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'Home',
            'url' => ['site/index'],
            'options' => ['class' => 'xyz'], // this adds LI attributes
        ],
    ],
    'options' => ['class' => 'abc'], // this adds UL attributes
]);
```

Comment: Hello @Bizley, Thanks for your comment, as I mentioned it's about Nav::widget, according to your answer the main UL Nav::widget's class is changed by second 'op'(Which contain 'nav' class as the default value), but it doesn't work for the Nav::widget's items as a 'label' is required

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem - `items > options` work for sure in LI...